# Render image smaller with PHP

Tags: php, image, render

In my website I got like 10GB of images but 90% of that images are really huge. And what I need is to render them in thumbnail, but I don't want to create thumbnail for each image. And I create a code for resize it and print it in PHP and just call the PHP.

But I also need the follow data, that I don't know how to add it.

```
<img src="<? echo $img; ?>" width="<? echo $width; ?>" height="<? echo $height; ?>" alt="<? echo $descr; ?>" tag='<? echo $tags; ?>' id="img_idea"/>
```

How could I add all this information?

Thnaks

Comment: You really really want to pre-generate your images, or at least to cache the ones you have generated.

Comment: I got my images like 500K each one. And I want to make thumbnails like 50k more or less

Comment: when you say data you mean the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned with Bandwidth you'll want to make SMALLER new copies of your big images when they are uploaded.

If you are also concerned with space, you can create a page (i.e. www.mysite.com/image.php?imgid=133) that will look up the images, check for the smaller version, create it if it does not exist, then serve the smaller version.

Check out PHP GD and the numerous plugins that stem from it to figure out how to resize the images.

If you're NOT concerned with Bandwidth, you can wrap your img in a div, then apply the desired width/height to the div and max-width: 100%; and max-height: 100% to the img.

Comment: Hi tiger,

The Bandwidth is not a problem, but when you load the page its too slow. And I make the image with PHP GD, but i need to add alt, tags and id. How could i do that?

Comment: If you use my suggestion of having a page (image.php?q=id) which renders them, simply use that as your HREF and make your anchor tag like normal...? I'm not sure I understand your question. Above, in your own example, should work just as well for adding info to the img tags

Comment: Hi tiger, Well forgot tags, i need to add an id for control. How could i do this adding. (image.php?q=id). And if you said that i save a temp file in server I can't because many images and many users at same time. We can't do that

Comment: Still not really understanding the question... A workflow for one of my websites is like this: 1) User uploads photo to server 2) Server uses PHP GD to resize one image to a thumbnail and the other to the max image size, then saves both in a specific folder (i.e. /img/users/10-thumb.jpg or /img/users/10-full.jpg), then the page /images/serve.php?type=user&id=10&size=thumb will simply readfile that to the browser (don't forget to set Content-Type!!!)